# C# File.ReadAllText returning "NotSupportedException"

Tags: c#, file, filereader

There seems to be a problem with File.ReadAllText because it's returning "NotSupportedException" even when the target file exists. No matter what is put into the parameter, it keeps throwing the same exception.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(@"‪C:\Test.txt"));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And yes... Text.txt does exist in this directory. StreamReader has the exact same problem. Is there any workaround for this?

Compiler notes: "Additional information: The given path's format is not supported."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you decode the string

```
String report = String.Join(" ", @"‪C:\Test.txt".Select(c => ((int) c).ToString("x4")));

Console.Write(report);
```

You'll get

> **202a** 0043 003a 005c 0054 0065 0073 0074 002e 0074 0078 0074

As you can see, the path starts with the strange **U202a** character which is *Bidirectional text control character*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters

and thus *can't be used* as a part of a path name and so you get `NotSupportedException` (File System doesn't support `U202a` in the path name)

Comment: Good find Dmitry! You confirm my suspicions.

Comment: Thanks, I retyped the path which removed the invalid character.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx), a `NotSupportedException` indicates:

> path is in an invalid format.

Probably there is a non-visible character in your path, or your verbatim operator (`@`) is missing in your actual code, making `\t` a tab character.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't the case. Doing this: "C:\\Text.txt" doesn't help.

Comment: Try to remove the entire string, including quotes, and type it again. That might indicate there are invalid characters in the path.

Comment: Retying it helped. There were invalid characters in the string. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In My case I faced the same Exception but it was Administrator permission not set to the particular drive. I opened VSTS as an administrator and ran the same program then it worked properly.