# Invalid Filepath Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, file

when I try to read a file in C# with VS 2017 I get the following error:

System.NotSupportedException

[image: Visual Studio Screenshot]

Here is the code I use:

```
File.ReadAllText("‪D:\\Projects\\text.txt");
```

Which gets the System.NotSupportedException.

What is mistery, is that the file exists and the path is valid in other tools.

I can even use functions like this, without errors:

```
Path.GetFileName("‪D:\\Projects\\text.txt")
```

And it returns: "text.txt"
So the path should be valid.

I use the .Net Framework 4.6 and Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Can you open this file in notepad?

Comment: Yes, I can open it with notepath. But with vs 2017 i can´t read any file.

Comment: The code works one my other computer with visual studio 2015. Or maybe it is a file security permission error?

Comment: yes, it sounds like the problem with permissions

Comment: And File.WriteAllText("‪D:\\Projects\\text.txt", "text") works. But not reading the file.

Comment: Any idea how I can edit the permissions, because I dont think I have changed anything from the standard windows 10 configuration.

Comment: Visual Studio is an IDE, this is not related to Visual Studio unless you are developing an add-in/extension, which you didn't mention. So, please read [ask] before asking the next question so you don't add incorrect information. Also, please post entire stack traces and error messages, not screenshots.

Comment: Camilo a think it is a Visual Studio 2017, or .Net 4.6 bug. So it is important for the question.

Comment: No, it's not important at all. Visual Studio does not exist after the program is compiled. You didn't say anywhere in the question that you are targeting .NET 4.6 though, and that's actually useful information

Comment: It can be a problem with the visual studio debugger (maybe it gets invalid exceptions) so it is important to mention the visual studio version.

Comment: According to the Reference [Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/permissions/fileiopermission.cs,b2a474881a0dd2f5), this exception is thrown if the path "has invalid volume separator". Double-check the actual source string.

Comment: Thx mark, but I have already checked it. The path should be valid. If I use the File.WriteAllText function I can use it and set its content. But reading the file does not work. So I think it is a .net or visual studio bug.

Comment: Well, I don't think it can be a VS bug if you're calling this from a compiled program.

Comment: The compiled program still contains logik for the debugger (i have not used the release build function).

Comment: Maybe a stupid proposal, but try switching off your antivirus program and retry. Mine gives me annoying effects from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is a non-printable character in your string.
Open Notepad, write your path there (**NOT** copy-paste, **re-type** it with your keyboard). 
Then delete your string from your code and copy-paste it from notepad.

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37654824/c-sharp-file-readalltext-returning-notsupportedexception).

EDIT: Yep, that's the problem. Your invisible character is displayed as an arrow in the image below.

[image]

EDIT2: Please copy the following line

```
Path.GetFileName("D:\\Project\\text.txt");
```

and replace it in your code. The encoding should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, but it don´t get a invisible char there. Even if I type the path without copying it, the same error is displayed.

Comment: alright, create a new text file in the same folder, fill it with some text and try your code on it. does it work?

Comment: Yes, PathInternal.HasInvalidVolumeSeparator() produces this exception.

Comment: I can not open any file. Now I have created a new project with Visual Studio 2015 and copyed the .cs code file into the project and now it can read files. So I assume there is a bug in visual studio 2017.